# Django + MySQL IntegrityError on save()

Tags: mysql, django

I have the following model that represents IP addresses:

```
class Ip(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

A process is sending IP parameters to a function, which should UPSERT Ip rows into the database.

This works OK, until the process starts to "bombard" with IPs, which sometimes (about 1 in every few hundreds requests) throws the following error:

`IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1.2.3.4' for key 'PRIMARY'")`

Why does this happen?
Why does Django try to INSERT when this row already exists (it's defined as **primary key**)?
How can I solve this issue without manually SELECTing and then deciding whether to INSERT or UPDATE?

We're using `Django 1.5.1`

EDIT:
Here's how we do the upsert:

```
obj = Ip(ip='1.2.3.4', ...)
obj.save()
```

According to the docs (and our experience), this should perform an UPSERT operation, based on the primary key `ip` which **always** has a value.

Comment: How do you save your model?

Comment: please paste a little code on how you are doing that, we can propose a solution based on that. Accroding to me you have specified IP as a primary key so when the same IP comes it gives integrity error

Comment: Edited with the code that is saving the model

Comment: Yes, if the primary key exists it should definitely do an update unless `force_insert` is `True`. Is this all there is to your code?

Comment: @knbk, yes. That's pretty much the code. As I mentioned, it only happens when there is a large amount of requests to upsert data into the table. Maybe this can shed some light...

Answer (score 1):

The `save` method is subject to a race condition regarding the primary key. It first determines if a record with that primary key exists, and if it does an update statement is executed, otherwise an insert statement is executed. If a concurrent requests inserts a new record between these two queries, there will be an integrity error.

The following will handle a race condition (unless records are deleted in between queries):

```
import sys
from django.utils import six

try:
    obj.save()
except IntegrityError:
    # The save might have been subject to a race condition. 
    # If it is, a record with this object's pk exists, so try to update it. 
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    try:
        obj.save(force_update=True)
    except:
        six.reraise(*exc_info)
```

If something else is wrong, this will raise the first, initial exception, so there are no hidden `IntegrityError`s besides the one that are caused by this race condition. I know it's a little verbose for a simple save, but you can always override the `save` method on your model to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks @knbk. The way our system works, an IP can enter the process only once, so race conditions are unlikely. Nevertheless, I will give your suggestion a try and update here later.